# Select value change not recognized and passed to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have my code set up like this:

First a select:

```
 <select id="select_order">
     <option value="0">Pick One</option>
     <option value="1">Ascending</option>
     <option value="2">Descending</option>
  </select>
```

And in my javascript:

```
var sortv= "database_percent";
var sorto= "asc";
$("#select_order").change(function(){
if (("#select_order").val == 1) {
sortv = "database_percent";
sorto = "asc";
}
else if (("#select_order").val == 2 ){
sortv = "database_percent";
sorto = "desc";
}
else {
alert("Pick something");
}
});

$.ajax({
url: 'all_get_2.php?category=ethnicity',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'JSON',
data: {sortvalue: sortv ,sortorder:sorto},
})
```

What I'm hoping to do is get the value selected from the dropdown and then pass those new variables (for sortv and sorto) into ajax. The AJAX is getting JSON from my PHP file, which is used to draw a Flot chart.

I set the variables of sortv and sorto above the if...else code, so that the AJAX has some variables to load the chart at first (and so it won't throw an error). However, when I select something different from the select, I'm getting the alert that corresponds with my ELSE condition. I have no idea why though.

Assuming I (i.e., you) can fix this, is this even the right approach to pass new data variables in AJAX? Should I actually expect my charts to redraw when those variables change if that code is my .done statement (not shown)?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .val() not .val to receive the value. val() is a function which can get or set the value for your field.

Also you should use $(this) inside the eventhandler function, because in your code, the event is called by your select field, so you don't need to reselect it by id:

```
$("#select_order").change(function(){
    var call = true;
    switch(parseInt($(this).val())) {
        case 1:
            sortv = "database_percent";
            sorto = "asc";
        break;
        case 2:
            sortv = "database_percent";
            sorto = "desc";
        break;
        default:
            call = false;
            alert("Pick something");
        break;
    }

    if(call) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'all_get_2.php?category=ethnicity',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {sortvalue: sortv ,sortorder:sorto},
            success: function(data) {
                // your response handler here
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Got it. That did the trick. The question is now how to pass the new variable into ajax...essentially "reload" ajax...is there a way to do that? I didn't want to wrap the change event around it all because I want the chart to render before someone picks from the select and then updates when they select.

Comment: how about using your the ajax call directly in your change event handler?

Comment: Actually, your editted code is giving me "Pick Something" every time. If I put the ajax call in the event handler, do I have to move around my .done as well?

Comment: The parseInt addition did the trick and this works great. Moved my "done" into the ajax and the selects work great. The only question I have now is how to load the chart before someone selects something (i.e., on page load) and then change when someone selects.

Comment: Place a `$(document).ready(function() { // load chart});` handler somewhere in your code. It will be executed if you calling the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68507/discussion-between-jonmrich-and-tyr).

Answer (score 1):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a function not a property.

So you need to use:

```
$("#select_order").val()
```

Additionally you are missing `$` before selector. and you can use `this.value` in your handler.

Comment: Got it. That did the trick. The question is now how to pass the new variable into ajax...essentially "reload" ajax...is there a way to do that? I didn't want to wrap the change event around it all because I want the chart to render before someone picks from the select and then updates when they select.